# Page Download Speed API Service

Tags: rest, pagespeed, load-time

I'm looking for a API online service that provides the page download speed of specific pages on different websites. The result should give me the load time in milliseconds (i.e. 3400 ms).
I've firstly seen Google's PageSpeed service, but it only gives me a useless 'score'. I'm actually unable to find any other service that fits my needs.

If possible, i'm looking for a REST service that gives me a good number of requests limit (at least 2500 / day).

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://www.webpagetest.org which has a restful API as well: https://sites.google.com/a/webpagetest.org/docs/advanced-features/webpagetest-restful-apis

You may need to run your own [private version of WebpageTest](https://sites.google.com/a/webpagetest.org/docs/private-instances) in order to use the restful API (the public one requires an API key).

Comment: Can you please explain me what do you mean with "You may need to run your own private version of WPT in order to use the restful API"? What is a public version of WPT?

Comment: WPT = WebpageTest (sorry about that, I updated the answer). webpagetest.org is the public version, but I think that in order to use the RESTful API you need to run your own version (It's open-source software).

Answer (score 0):

I am going to be brief here.

You can call **Page Speed Insights API by Google**. [Here](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v4/getting-started) it is.